# ViewPager to represent an array of data

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a class which serves as my model.

```
class Model {
    String name;
    String address;
}
```

I have an array of objects of this class with 'n' elements.

```
List<Model> modelElements;
```

I am trying to implement a ViewPager with 'n' number of Fragments. Each fragment in the ViewPager is exactly the same but the data shown is picked from each element of the Model. I have implemented a basic Fragment which has two TextViews, each for showing the name and address.

I want to know how can I pass the object of Model class to each Fragment. So modelElements[0] corresponds to the first Fragment in ViewPager, modelElements[1] corresponds to the second Fragment and so on.

One way could be to use Bundle. But the way ViewPager creates Fragments doesn't expose me to the FragmentTransaction.

```
class MyViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public MyViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        if (i == 0) {
            return MyFragment.newInstance();
        } else if (i == 1) {
            return MyFragment.newInstance();
        } else if (i == 2) {
            return MyFragment.newInstance();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

What is the best way to pass the data?

Also, this sounds stupid to me - create a new instance of the same Fragment for each set of different data. Is there some other construct that Android offers that will fit my requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Make your Model implement [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) interface.

2) Pass your model to `newInstance()` so it becomes `newInstance(Model model)`

3) In the `newInstance()` create bundle and set the argument for your fragment with a value of `model`

4) Retrieve the model from `onCreate` of the `fragment`

Comment: Should have thought of this. But is there no more graceful way? Is it required that a new Fragment be created for each instance of model data?

Comment: "But is there no more graceful way?" No it is the standard way. "Is it required that a new Fragment be created for each instance of model data?" Yes, and you have already done that in your code, have not you? what are `MyFragment.newInstance();` doing?

Comment: Yes, I have already done that. Was having this feeling that it is not right. :) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Below is Demo code i hv created to load different url in viewpage dynamically , however the there are dynamic urls passed to eachview in viewpage like below :

```
  // ... do other initialization, such as create an ActionBar ...

        pagerAdapter = new MainPagerAdapter();
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

        WebView w1 = new WebView(MainActivity.this);

        w1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        w1.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

        WebView w2 = new WebView(MainActivity.this);

        w2.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        w2.loadUrl("http://www.live.com");

        pagerAdapter.addView(w1, 0);
        pagerAdapter.addView(w2, 1);
```

[COMPLETE DEMO CODE](https://github.com/mtetno/DynamicViewPager/blob/master/src/com/mtetno/DynamicViewPager/MainActivity.java)